# Pen drive lifetime issues when running OS from it

Tags: installation, usb

I intend to install Ubuntu onto a 32GB pendrive. I've heard that the lifetime of a pendrive will reduce drastically due to the large number of read/writes due to running /tmp from pendrive. Does this issue really affect modern pendrives and how to use the RAM  as tmpfs instead of having /tmp in the pendrive?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this helps you in making your decision.

> Due to the additional write cycles that occur on a full-blown
>   installation, the life of the flash drive may be slightly reduced.
>   Like any solid state drive, USB thumb drives have limited rewritable
>   cells. Granted, these are quite long, but if you are using the drive
>   as RAM, this can run out relatively quickly.
>
> This doesn't apply to systems particularly designed for live systems
>   which keep all changes in RAM until the user logs off. A Live SD in a
>   USB flash card reader adapter is an effective way to avoid any duty
>   cycles on the flash medium from writes and circumvent this problem.
>   The SD card as a WORM device has an essentially unlimited life. An OS
>   such as Linux can then run from the live USB/SD card and use
>   conventional media for writing, such as magnetic disks, to preserve
>   system changes.
>
> Some disadvantages:
>
> - Limited Protection – Persistent Data is left unencrypted in most    cases. Lose your drive, someone could steal and use your data.
> - Persistent data is uncompressed – Although the Live OS can be    compressed, the persistent data is left uncompressed making it very
>     easy to run out of storage space quickly.
> - Some changes are not saved persistently – In some cases, further    modification is required to enable things like graphical card
>     settings and network card settings to be saved. In some cases, system 
>     wide updates do not work.

<sup>Sources: Pendrivelinux.com and ehow.com</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider.

- tmpfs mounted in ram = ramdisk. [fully covered here](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux)
- Disable swap (not needed, or use another fast pendrive for swap)
- Boot flag `noatime` (to reduce disk writes from ram to disk) [link](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/08/gain-30-linux-disk-performance-noatime-nodiratime-relatime/)
- Boot flag `toram` (Load all once and stop further disk reading)

If you let enough free space after install needed things, in theory it will suvive untill you have no more free blocks to redirect badblocks. When you run out of space and a new block gets corrputed dataloss starts to happen. If you reserve 10gb of free space it will be used to redirect inodes to working blocks. Using Class 10 sdcard much better than using Class 6, from several thousands to millions disk writes. There's one online article -which i do not remember link- with a tool and a test over real pendrives being fried to check their real limits. You could stop using for Linux when you start to loss cells, inode redirecting messages will come often when usb starts to die. At this moment you could clone the USB to a new one and use this current USB for dummy, transport files, save movies... and why not, format it again excluding badblocks from scratch ([look at](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/locating-and-correcting-bad.html))

If you have ENOUGH ram, you could try to boot to ram (boot flag `toram`) the full operating system (both for livecd or fully installed), this will improve the usb speed once loaded, but will take a little more load. Running speed matters more than wait +5-10 seconds to boot.

Using LiveCD

using LiveCD + Persistence is a good idea if you like it. Persisten can be encrypted, and contain temporal data that will be added to the current running system, like modules, software or config files.

Here you can see a compreensive tut [click click](https://calvin.me/create-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-live-usb-even-boots-ram/) to create your own live from your preferred Distro with Persistence, and with an extra to boot to ram option in Grub.

There's also Android App to serve img as usb drive, so you can boot your LiveImage storing and serving it from phone to computer. If you boot to ram you could just boot and remove the memory. Use any extra usb for your HOME

Mahts, theory, and brands appart, i do suggest you to just do it and learn from experience. Using sdcards makes you easier to "get a value" of it's quality by given Class number.

Interesting note: eMMC and SSD splits block/inode usage seammessly, a basic sdcard / flashmemory will fry blocks till is over. I don't really see the difference, a badblock can be always be relocated, it is only write unable, but readable.

Feel free to consider im am not hdd, sdcard and filesystem expert so i may be wrong in one or many assumptios. My frist try is always check for truth.